# smartparens' (sp-pair "⟨" "⟩" :wrap "C-*") doesn't work

Tags: smartparens

The following config:

```lisp
(require 'smartparens)
(smartparens-mode t)
(smartparens-global-mode t)
(sp-pair "⟨" "⟩" :wrap "C-*")
```

doesn't work. Indeed:

- running `C-x C-e` on the last line seems to be OK (the minibuffer just contains a very long list starting with `((LaTeX-mode (:open "\\lvert" :close "\\rvert" :trigger "\\lvert" :actions (wrap insert autoskip navigate) :when`,
- but, if I run `C-*`, the `*Messages*` buffer just displays:

  ```
    Mark set
    Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, nil
  ```

and the cursor jumps to the end of the following word.

Do you know how to fix this issue?

### Caveat

I must admit my config file is not trivial (it is essentially based on `[emacs-leuven][1]`) but I couldn't test with an empty config. Indeed, despite:

```
$ ls /home/bitouze/.emacs.d/elpa/smartparens-20220623.1523/smartparens.el
/home/bitouze/.emacs.d/elpa/smartparens-20220623.1523/smartparens.el
```

in an `emacs -Q` session, running `M-x load-file RET /home/bitouze/.emacs.d/elpa/smartparens-20220623.1523/smartparens.el RET` leads to:

```
Loading /home/bitouze/.emacs.d/elpa/smartparens-20220623.1523/smartparens.el (source)...
eval-buffer: Cannot open load file: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type, dash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your pair before enabling the mode. Try:

```lisp
(require 'smartparens)
(sp-pair "⟨" "⟩" :wrap "C-*")
(smartparens-mode t)
(smartparens-global-mode t)
```